# Where are those snapshot bundles required by Tycho build?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho, p2

When building CBI aggregator from Git source (https://github.com/eclipse-cbi/p2repo-aggregator/) I always come across errors due to some snapshot bundle requirements. For example,

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bundleLocation not found: /home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/emf/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi/2.16.0-SNAPSHOT/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bundleLocation not found: /home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/emf/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi/2.16.0-SNAPSHOT/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bundleLocation not found: /home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/orbit/bundles/org.apache.commons.logging/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.commons.logging-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bundleLocation not found: /home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/orbit/bundles/org.apache.commons.logging/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.commons.logging-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

However, I just can't find any official P2 repositories that provide with snapshot bundles after switching through all `download.eclipse.org/releases/` repositories.
Guys building Eclipse IDE must have such repo to provide with snapshot bundles, but where for an outsider?

Comment: Is [`https://download.eclipse.org/staging/2022-03/`](https://download.eclipse.org/staging/2022-03/) what you're looking for?

Comment: @howlger , you made my day! I have been desperately contributing a considerable amount of time to solving the dependency issues of Eclipse, thanks a lot! By the way, what is this repo for? I have never known the significance of this repo before! Maybe a snapshot version of `ibm.icu` I'm looking for lies just within it!

Comment: This repo is for the upcoming [Eclipse IDE 2022-03 release](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipseide/2022-03/). The [68 projects](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03) build their artifacts themselves. Based on the [.aggrcon files here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/simrel/org.eclipse.simrel.build.git/tree/), the project artifacts are aggregated into the repo. [The IDE packages are then built from the repo by EPP](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages), Tycho and [this Jenkins job](https://ci.eclipse.org/packaging/job/simrel.epp-tycho-build/).

Comment: But if you're looking for dependencies for your RCP application, then better look for the repo with the latest artifacts of an Eclipse project by [starting from here](https://projects.eclipse.org/), going to the project, tab _Downloads_ (e.g. [here for EMF](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.emf.emf/downloads)) or going to the project website to the download section (which can differ from project to project). Repos of non-Eclipse stuff used by Eclipse projects can be found in [Eclipse Orbit](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/).

Comment: @matt It seems Howlger is accustomed to adding his answer in the comment section though he is an Eclipse expert. I would like to accept his answer in one of my previous questions but he didn't post any answer anyway though I've told him already. I will appreciate it if you can inform him of that.

Comment: You can answer yourself!  This is the best way to be helpful to others, with a complete question and answer pair. Stack Overflow is an encyclopedia in QA format. Comments are volatile but answers are more likely to persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://download.eclipse.org/staging/ is what I'm looking for, according to what @howlger said.

Comment: I'm suddenly getting this for org.apache.commons.logging-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with a Tycho 0.24.0 build. Who even needs this dependency and where would you add this repository? Certainly not to the build target because the application being built doesn't need it...?